# Checking multiple divs to see if h3 is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check each instance of `.menu-section` to see if the `.menu-title` div contains a `h3` title. If it does then it should output the appropriate `console.log` message. I can't figure out where I am going wrong as logically it seems to make sense to me. Any help would be awesome.

```js
$(".menu-section").each(function() {
  if ($('.menu-title h3').length) {
    console.log("menu-title h3 exists");
  } else {
    console.log("menu-title h3 does not exist");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrapper nav-spacer">
    <div class="menu-container content-container">
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item">
            <h3>PLUS SIZE &amp; CURVE</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item">
            <h3>PETITE</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Working CodePen: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/zQExRd?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you're looking at *all* `.menu-title` elements in the `each()` loop, not just the one within the current `.menu-section` element. You need to use the `this` keyword to reference the current element, then `find()` the element you're looking for:

```js
$(".menu-section").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.menu-title h3').length) {
    console.log("menu-title h3 exists");
  } else {
    console.log("menu-title h3 does not exist");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrapper nav-spacer">
    <div class="menu-container content-container">
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item">
            <h3>PLUS SIZE &amp; CURVE</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item">
            <h3>PETITE</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-section">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-title menu-item"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect Rory! Thank you, I'll accept the answer once I can.